# How to pass input parameters into a POST method in api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, postman, aws-api-gateway

so im using API gateway (Amazon web services). I made a simple post method called "addUser" which takes in several string parameters (username, firstName,email, etc) and generates a user in my usertable (dynamoDB). The problem is, when I deploy the API, i get the following error:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Get methods can take input just fine, but my Post methods cannot. And i have no idea how to solve this.

Here is a screen shot of my user API
[image]

Here is the invoke url:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/userAPI/adduser
```

Here is my input model i used in the method request:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "email":{"type":"string"},
        "birthdate":{"type":"string"},
        "firstName":{"type":"string"},
        "lastName":{"type":"string"},
        "userName":{"type":"string"},
        "phoneNumber":{"type":"string"},
        "profileImageURL":{"type":"string"}
    },
    "title":"InputaddUser"
}
```

And here is the input body i used in postman:

```
{
  "email": "qteenfadfaf1@gmail.com",
  "birthdate": "1/1/1990",
  "firstName": "Qafasdmafdfadfafr",
  "lastName": "Ffafafadasdfafrooqfsaui",
  "username": "Caster7",
  "phoneNumber": "some #",
  "profileImageRef ":"something"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'missing authentication token' message means you aren't actually sending a POST request. Try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to easily test your APIs. I tested with the API URL you provided (which I removed in the post) and it worked for me with a POST method.

With cURL try `curl -X POST ...`